# Running firebase functions inside a docker container for development purpose

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-functions

I would like to develop and test a google firebase cloud functions in a docker container. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.11.5
WORKDIR /workspace

RUN npm install -g firebase-tools eslint babel-cli

ADD functions-source/package*.json functions-source/
RUN npm --prefix ./functions-source install

ADD ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS /workspace/keys/default-appengine-service-key.json
EXPOSE 9005 5000
```

I build the image above with this command

```
docker build --tag dewey-nguyen:latest .
```

Then start a docker container with this command:

```
docker run -p 9005:9005 -p 5000:5000 -o 0.0.0.0 -v `pwd`:/workspace -it dewey-nguyen:latest /bin/bash
```

When I got inside of the container, I log in to firebase with this command:

```
firebase login
```

and I was able to sign in to firebase in the browser (`http://localhost:9005/...`) from host machine.

When I run `firebase serve --only functions --debug` inside of my container, I see all functions are green:

```
✔  functions: auth: http://localhost:5000/dewey-nguyen/us-central1/auth
✔  functions: myInformedDelivery: http://localhost:5000/dewey-nguyen/us-central1/myInformedDelivery
✔  functions: authCallback: http://localhost:5000/dewey-nguyen/us-central1/authCallback
✔  functions: checkInformedDeliveryEmails: http://localhost:5000/dewey-nguyen/us-central1/checkInformedDeliveryEmails
```

But I am not able to access `http://localhost:5000/dewey-nguyen/us-central1/auth` from the host browser with `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error returned.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: hey @Dewey, hope this: https://github.com/lgvalle/firebase-tools-docker can be as useful for you as it was to me :)

Comment: Hey @Dewey, you can see my repo here => https://github.com/Bolket/next-firebase-functions. I use docker with firebase and nextjs ;)

Comment: @Dewey how did you solve this eventually?

Answer (score 8):

I've just went the same problem here, fixed by using the following command `firebase serve --only functions -o 0.0.0.0`.
Using this option you still can access by localhost on your host machine.

You can also map your `.config` folder, something like `-v "${HOME}/.config":"/root/.config"` to keep your logged account, because your firebase session is stored in there.

Comment: Additionally, if you use the functions Firebase Emulator, you can set an `emulators.<emulator_name>.host` property in the firebase.json file to `"0.0.0.0"`.